# NetSuite hide form tabs based on role

Tags: netsuite

I have been looking through NetSuite's help, and I am coming up empty. Is it possible to use SuiteScript to hide a tab on a form? I see you can pull back a form and grab that tab from that (form.getTab('info');) but unlike with fields there is no option for form.getTab('info').setDisplayType('hidden'); or anything along those lines. Does anyone have any suggestions on this? We have multiple organizations using this form and some fields are not relevant to some of the organizations.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We (the TNO team) looked into this for you. Confirmed with NetSuite, there is no direct API that could hide a customb tab. What could be done though, is to hide all the fields that are present to the tab you would like to hide. Through it, the tab will not be displayed.

Under nlobjfield, you can use the setDisplayType() and set the type to hidden.

For reference, you may check the following link in SuiteAnswers:

- https://netsuite.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/10263/kw/nlobjField#N917407985-10

Hope this helps! Let us know if you need any other help. As said before, we are *The New Office (TNO)*, a NetSuite consultancy and reseller that helps companies adopt NS and other cloud applications. We are working on our new site ([thenewoffice.com), but our former site is here [http://vconstruct.com/]. We also have a product site for data migration tools, http://www.muvdata.com/

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

There is no command to hide a Sub-Tab that's already showing.

Have you considered hiding the Sub-Tab by default for all users, and then using form.insertSubTab() if the user's Role (or Group or whatever you want to use) is in your allowed list?

Comment: That is a good idea, but cannot be supported in this case. Thank you for the response

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, although not officially support via `SuiteScript` or simply just a custom field. There are no `SuiteScript API`s to do this; you need to do `DOM` manipulation.

The major downside, should `NetSuite` decide to change their `DOM` elements, you're tab hiding most likely will not work.

Use something like `Firebug` or `Chrome debugger` to find the `ID` of the tab you want to hide and add a custom `HTML` field in a spot AFTER the tab on your screen (tab needs to be loaded) and include:

```
document.getElementById("tabID").style.display="none";
```